# Lubuntu 14.04.1 - Accent suddenly disappear mainly in Vim and GVim

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, input-language

Recently I made a fresh install of Lubuntu 14.04.1 in my netbook.

Now when I open Vim or Gvim and after switching applications windows, the accent (in my case is Portuguese Brasil) get disabled suddenly.

What I can do to solve that?

Comment: What do you mean by disabled? Does it disappear?

Comment: Yes @Galgalesh, it disappear. When I want to enter, e.g., á, Vim / GVim give me a space and a, or ê, it give me a space and e.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I'm not using Lubuntu myself, but let me give you a hint which might help.

Open a terminal window and run `ibus-setup`. If you select the *Advanced* tab, you should find an option "Share the same input method among all applications". Make sure that option is checked.

Comment: Thanks @Gunnar Hjalmarsson, I already tried that but the problem persists.